# How to loop coords in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array with coords like [1,1], [1,2], [2,1],[2,2]
but I can't loop it...

```js
var fieldCoords = [];
var fieldCoordX = fieldCoordY = 1;
while (fieldCoordY < 8) {
  fieldCoords.push[fieldCoordX, fieldCoordY];
  console.log(fieldCoordY);
  if (fieldCoordY < 8) {
    fieldCoordX++;
    console.log(fieldCoordY);
  }
  fieldCoordY++;
}
```

Can you give me some hint? Thanks

Comment: `for(const [x,y] of coords) console.log(x,y)`

Comment: You're logging `fieldCoordY` to console. What is the final value of `fieldCoords`?

Comment: It  doubles numbers like 1,1 then 2,2 etc. Thanks for afford.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two nested [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops for the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```js
var fieldCoords = [], i, j;

for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < 8; j++) {
        fieldCoords.push([i, j]);
    }
}

console.log(fieldCoords);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```